# OleDbConnection missing in System.Data.OleDb on System.Data.dll 2.0.5.0 for Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, oledb

I can see those OleDb classes in document here: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.ConnectionString/

But seems it does not exists in System.Data.dll version 2.0.5.0:
[image]

seems some guys also got same problem:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/62619/no-oledbconnect-in-system-data-oledb-name-space
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17728/help-how-can-using-name-space-system-data-oledb-on-mac

does anyone have idea on this ?

Answer (score 1):

The API is an extended subset of Silverlight: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/available-assemblies/#Overview

The API docs pull from the original class in the BCL(Thus it is incorrect as you noticed in the Assembly). `System.Data.dll` overall has some functionality removed as noted here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/system.data/#System.Data

Comment: Feel free to upvote and mark as answered if this explains your problem.